# Calculation using binomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics

I am supposed to find the term, which does not contain x in: $$\left ( \frac{2x}{y}-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2x} \right )^{12}$$ Is my solution correct?

$$\left ( \frac{2x}{y}-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2x} \right )^{12}=\sum _{k_{1}+k_{2}=12}(2x(y)^{-1})^{k_{1}}\left ( -\sqrt{y}(2x)^{-1} \right )^{k_{2}}$$
$$k_{1}-k_{2}=0$$$$k_{1}+k_{2}=12$$So$$k_{1}=12,k_{2}=0$$ So$$\binom{12}{12,0}=1$$Is that correct?

Comment: Shouldn't $k_1=k_2=6$ be the solution to the two equations? Also you are missing $\binom{12}{k_1}$ in the expression for the sum.

Comment: @AnuragA Can you describe it more?

Comment: Is it $$\frac{495}{16x^4}$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner how can that be the answer, OP wants the term free of $x$.

Comment: Ok, i have misread the problem, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
\begin{align*}
\left ( \frac{2x}{y}-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2x} \right )^{12} & = \sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{12}{i}\left(\frac{2x}{y}\right)^{12-i}\left(\frac{y^{1/2}}{2x}\right)^i\\
& = \sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{12}{i}2^{12-i}x^{12-i}y^{i-12}y^{i/2}2^{-i}x^{-i}\\
& = \sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{12}{i}2^{12-2i}x^{12-2i}y^{\frac{3i}{2}-12}
\end{align*}
You want a term free of $x$ so, $12-2i=0$, implying that $i=6$. So the term which is free of $x$ is 
$$\binom{12}{6}y^{-3}=924y^{-3}.$$

Comment: Oh, okay, my solution was completely wrong.. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac{2x}{y}-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2x}\right)^{12}$=\sum_{k=0}^{12} {12 \choose k} \left(\frac{2x}{y}\right )^k \left(\frac{-\sqrt{y}}{2x}\right)^{12-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{12} {12 \choose k} 2^{2k-12} (-1)^{12-k} y^{(12-3k)/2} x^{2k-12}.$$ let us choose $k=6$ to make the power of $x$ zero. So the term free of $x$ is
$${12 \choose 6}y^{-3}$$

Comment: Thank you so much